# Chave de array preenchido com uma expressão vinda de uma query SQL

Tags: php, array, funções

O que isso quer dizer exatamente?

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [MAX(nr_ficha)] => 13
    )
)
```

Dei um *print* na tela e vi que minha chave estrangeira (`nr_ficha`) está recebendo valor 13 (que sim, é o último valor da tabela), mas não entendo o restante do código e nem por que ele não funciona.

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\TESTE_BANCADA\Models\Teste.php on line 16
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`teste__bancada`.`teste`, CONSTRAINT `nr_ficha_teste` FOREIGN KEY (`nr_ficha`) REFERENCES `cab_teste` (`nr_ficha`)) in C:\xampp\htdocs\TESTE_BANCADA\Models\Teste.php:18 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\TESTE_BANCADA\Models\Teste.php(18): PDO->exec('INSERT INTO tes...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\TESTE_BANCADA\Controllers\processa_testeq.php(30): Teste->cadastrar_teste(Array, '4', '4', '1') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\TESTE_BANCADA\Models\Teste.php on line 18

A função que eu usei foi essa:

```
public function busca_ficha(){
$conexao = Database::getConnection();

$select="SELECT MAX(nr_ficha) FROM cab_teste";

  $busca = $conexao->query($select);
  $nr_ficha = $busca->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  return $nr_ficha;
}
```

E a chamei dessa forma:

```
$ficha = new Cabecalho();
$nr_ficha = $ficha->busca_ficha();
```

Alguém me ajude, please.

Comment: Porque é o retorno do `MySQL` você pode apelidar o campo com `AS`, ficaria assim: `$select="SELECT MAX(nr_ficha) AS apelido FROM cab_teste";`. O `AS` também pode ser implícito, ficando assim: `$select="SELECT MAX(nr_ficha) apelido FROM cab_teste";`.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

O que o mecanismo de comunicação com o banco de dados que você usou pega o resultado da *query* e coloca em um *array* associativo (note que mesmo as pessoas achando que PHP é orientada a objeto, boa parte de sua biblioteca incentiva o uso do bom e velho *array* associativo e não usa uma classe). Então cada elemento desse *array* tem uma chave e valor. O que te interessa mais é o valor, mas para se chegar nele precisa da chave com um nome e este nome é o nome da coluna no banco de dados. Neste caso você usou uma expressão para obter a coluna e não deu um nome, então ele usa a expressão como nome, que é o que veio do banco de dados.

Se deseja que tenha um nome, coloque ele na *query*, assim:

```
SELECT MAX(nr_ficha) AS ULTIMO FROM cab_teste
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Max.sql).

O que fará retornar o resultado:

> ```
> Array
> (
> [0] => Array
>     (
>         [ULTIMO] => 13
>     )
> )
> ```

Mas alguma coisa me diz que está fazendo coisa que não deve. Se dois clientes fizerem o mesmo eles receberão o mesmo número e se for cadastrar algo baseado nele terá duplicidade.

Comment: Você diz usar o mesmo valor de chave estrangeira? Isso não seria possível, pois a chave primária da outra tabela é auto incremento, então sempre que a linha filha receber um valor, vai ser maior que o penúltimo da linha mãe.

Comment: E esse Array continua sendo um encosto no projeto. Não queria apenas printá-lo, queria passá-lo para a chave estrangeira. Isso não acontece de forma alguma.

Comment: Bom, mas a minha pergunta não foi essa. Obrigada, sua resposta ao menos me ajudou a entender onde estou errando.

Comment: Não, não falei em chave primária, estrangeria, nada disso, estou falando do *array* associativo. Se não entende o que é um faça uma pergunta (verifique antes se já não tem no site). Não faço a mínima ideia do que está querendo fazer, mas parece solução errada, eu repensaria tudo isso. De fato a pergunta feita, é outra e foi o que respondi :)